# Getting 404 for Rails Static Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Carrierwave to handle file uploads. Files get stored under public/uploads/. Project uses Ember.js templates, and the img tags point to the proper src. (I've verified that the files are present at those paths.) However, the server returns a 404 for each.

It looks like this is a common problem, and the common solution is to:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

However, this isn't working. I'm still getting 404s. Any other ideas about how to deal with this?

It should be noted that I'm not using Apache or nginx.

Comment: What Rails version? How are you making the tags?

Comment: Rails 4. Img tags aren't built with an erb file, but with a handlebars template. They assume the format: `<img src="/uploads/project_logo/file/1/wilogo.png" data-bindattr-22="22" class="image-list__img">`

Comment: Is this only in production?

Comment: Yes, only in production. In development, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Rails no longer compiles the assets without digests. In order for this to work properly, you need to use a rails helper to include the proper asset name (with the digest), or use a gem like https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets as a workaround.

Comment: Related reading: https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/non-digested-asset-names-in-rails-4-your-options/

Comment: This is good to know, but might not be the problem. Tried alexspeller's gem and it didn't do the trick. (On 4.1.4.) Even when I `config.assets.digest = false`, the problem persists.

Comment: I would be willing to bet that this is almost certainly the issue. You would have a lot better luck if you could use the properly digested name (are your templates in erb?). If not, fir up firebug and hit the page. You'll notice the missed requests have the digest. If you navigate your production file server, the assets will not be there.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using erb files. These are handlebars templates. Neither the generated url nor the actual path are digested. Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: Although it's possible to create erb handlebars templates, that doesn't really work here. Basically, when you create an erb handlebars template, you'll hard-code whatever the erb references into the template. This is great if you're referring to a single image, such as a site logo. But in this case, we need different images for each of the objects that the template  renders, and erb files can't handle that.